# Check if any word is outside left page margin

Tags: vba, ms-word

1. document has multiple sections (section breaks), so start xSec = 3
2. check the first word of each paragraph (carriage return) is inside page's left margin
3. do not need to check inside of tables
4. At the end, I was planning on recording page number in an array for those pages that had words outside of left margin.

Any help is appreciated... thanks, Bruce

---

```vb
Sub LoopThroughParas()
    Dim doc As Word.Document, rng As range, i As Long, c As Word.Cell
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim sec As Word.Section, sr As range
    Dim xSec As Integer: xSec = 3
    Dim j As Integer: j = 1
    Dim list As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim pgNum As Integer
    Dim para As paragraph
    
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    leftMargin = ActiveDocument.PageSetup.leftMargin

    Debug.Print "hello1"
    For xSec = xSec To doc.Sections.count
       Set sec = doc.Sections(xSec)
       Debug.Print "hello2"
        For Each para In sec.range.Paragraphs
            j = j + 1
            Set firstWord = para.range.Words(1)
            If firstWord.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) < leftMargin Then
                Debug.Print j & "    " & firstWord
            End If
        Next para
    Next  'for each section break

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have just solved my own question... I used " first line of paragraph" option to compare against the left page margin... it identified many places that paragraphs were outside of the margin...

Comment: If this is true, you'd like to accept your answer and close this answer. If you shared your code, that'll be better. Thanks.

Comment: Please update your answer with the relevant code so that others can learn from this Q&A